# Add up a column of numbers at the Unix shell

Tags: linux, unix, shell

Given a list of files in `files.txt`, I can get a list of their sizes like this:

```
cat files.txt | xargs ls -l | cut -c 23-30
```

which produces something like this:

```
  151552
  319488
 1536000
  225280
```

How can I get the **total** of all those numbers?

Answer (score 449, accepted):

```
... | paste -sd+ - | bc
```

is the shortest one I've found (from the [UNIX Command Line](http://www.unixcl.com/2009/11/sum-of-numbers-in-file-unix.html) blog).

**Edit:** added the `-` argument for portability, thanks @Dogbert and @Owen.

Comment: Nice. Need the last - on Solaris too

Comment: `alias sum="paste -sd+ - | bc"` added to shell completion, thanks mate

Comment: `. . .| x=$(echo <(cat)); echo $((0+${x// /+}+0))` if you want all bash all the time:

Comment: @slf, watch out, you just overloaded `/usr/bin/sum`

Comment: too bad one can't crosspost answers to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com

Comment: Beware, `bc` is not available on some systems! `awk`, on the other hand is (I believe) required for POSIX compliance.

Comment: Thanks for this, added an alias for `sumlist`. Using this all the time now for aggregating counts from log files.

Comment: don@oysters:~/Documents$ cat tax | paste -sd+ - | bc
(standard_in) 2: syntax error

Comment: @donbright, make sure every line of the input file contains exactly one number, and nothing else. You can debug it by leaving off the `| bc`, and visually inspecting the output to spot the syntax error (it should be in the format "_a_ + _b_ + _c_ + ...").

Comment: When the start of the pipe (... in the above) can produce zero lines you might want to see "0" rather then "", you can get this using this instead: ... | (cat && echo 0) | paste -sd+ | bc

Answer (score 171):

Here goes

```
cat files.txt | xargs ls -l | cut -c 23-30 | 
  awk '{total += $1}END{print total}'
```

Comment: Using awk is a fine idea, but why keep the `cut`? That's a predictable column number, so use `... | xargs ls -l | awk '{total = total + $5}{END{print total}' `

Comment: You are correct of course - it was easier just to append on to the end of what was already there :-)

Comment: One bracket too much in @dmckee's answer :)

Comment: To make this a bit shorter, you could use `total+=$1` instead of `total = total + $1`

Answer (score 11):

Instead of using *cut* to get the file size from output of *ls -l*, you can use directly:

```
$ cat files.txt | xargs ls -l | awk '{total += $5} END {print "Total:", total, "bytes"}'
```

Awk interprets "$5" as the fifth column. This is the column from *ls -l* that gives you the file size.

Answer (score 11):

cat will not work if there are spaces in filenames. here is a perl one-liner instead.

```
perl -nle 'chomp; $x+=(stat($_))[7]; END{print $x}' files.txt
```

Comment: With the `-l` option to perl, the `chomp;` is unnecessary. The `-l` takes care of that.

Answer (score 10):

The whole ls -l and then cut is rather convoluted when you have **stat**. It is also vulnerable to the exact format of **ls -l** (it didn't work until I changed the column numbers for **cut**)

Also, fixed the [useless use of cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat).

```
<files.txt xargs stat -c %s | paste -sd+ - | bc
```

Comment: Huh.  Been using Unix for 32 years, and never knew that `<infile command` is the same as (and in a better order than) `command <infile`.

Answer (score 9):

```
python3 -c"import os; print(sum(os.path.getsize(f) for f in open('files.txt').read().split()))"
```

Or if you just want to sum the numbers, pipe into:

```
python3 -c"import sys; print(sum(int(x) for x in sys.stdin))"
```

Comment: `... | python -c'import sys; print(sum(int(x) for x in sys.stdin))'` when python 2 disappears at the end of this year.

Comment: don@oysters:~/Documents$ cat tax | python3 -c"import sys; print(sum(int(x) for x in sys.stdin))"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <genexpr>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n'

Answer (score 8):

if you don't have bc installed, try

```
echo $(( $(... | paste -sd+ -) ))
```

instead of

```
... | paste -sd+ - | bc
```

`$( )` <-- return the value of executing the command

`$(( 1+2 ))` <-- return the evaluated results

`echo` <-- echo it to the screen

Answer (score 6):

```
cat files.txt | awk '{ total += $1} END {print total}'
```

You can use the awk to do the same it even skips the non integers

```
$ cat files.txt
1
2.3
3.4
ew
1

$ cat files.txt | awk '{ total += $1} END {print total}'
7.7
```

or you can use ls command and calculate human readable output

```
$ ls -l | awk '{ sum += $5} END  {hum[1024^3]="Gb"; hum[1024^2]="Mb"; hum[1024]="Kb"; for (x=1024^3; x>=1024; x/=1024) { if (sum>=x) { printf "%.2f %s\n",sum/x,hum[x]; break; } } if (sum<1024) print "1kb"; }'
15.69 Mb

$ ls -l *.txt | awk '{ sum += $5} END  {hum[1024^3]="Gb"; hum[1024^2]="Mb"; hum[1024]="Kb"; for (x=1024^3; x>=1024; x/=1024) { if (sum>=x) { printf "%.2f %s\n",sum/x,hum[x]; break; } } if (sum<1024) print "1kb"; }'
2.10 Mb
```

Comment: You don't even need pipe: `awk '{ total += $1} END {print total}' files.txt` is quicker

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following script if you just want to use shell scripting without awk or other interpreters:

```
#!/bin/bash

total=0

for number in `cat files.txt | xargs ls -l | cut -c 23-30`; do
   let total=$total+$number
done

echo $total
```

Answer (score 5):

[TMTWWTDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it): Perl has a file size operator (-s)

```
perl -lne '$t+=-s;END{print $t}' files.txt
```

Comment: 9 years later... some perl golf: `perl -lne '$t+=-s}{print $t' files.txt`

Answer (score 3):

I would use "du" instead.

```
$ cat files.txt | xargs du -c | tail -1
4480    total
```

If you just want the number:

```
cat files.txt | xargs du -c | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}'
```

Comment: Disk usage != size of file. du reports disk usage.

Comment: I think the -b switch makes du do what I need.

Comment: @0x6adb015 Good knowledge. Thanks I hadn't realised.

Comment: That's a useful answer for the specific reason why the OP wanted the column of numbers added, but for the general number-adding case, it falls short.  (I use "du" all the time myself, but I came here looking for command-line math. :-) )

Comment: **This will not work when `files.txt` is large.** If the number of arguments piped to `xargs` reaches certain threshold, it breaks them up over multiple calls to `du`. The total shown at the end is the total for just the last call to `du`, not the whole list.

Answer (score 3):

In ksh:

```
echo " 0 $(ls -l $(<files.txt) | awk '{print $5}' | tr '\n' '+') 0" | bc
```

Comment: Good for picking up on skipping the `cut`, but you ignore awks ability to do the math...

Answer (score 3):

```
... |xargs|tr \  +|bc
... |paste -sd+ -|bc
```

The first command is just one symbol longer (note, it must have two spaces after the backslash!), but it handles the cases with empty lines in a column, whereas the second command results in an invalid expression with extra pluses.

E.g.:

```
echo "2
3
5

" | paste -sd+ -
```

results in

```
2+3+5++
```

which bc cannot handle, whereas

```
echo "2
3
5

" | xargs | tr \  +
```

gives a valid expression

```
 2+3+5
```

which can be piped into bc to get the final result

Answer (score 2):

Here's mine

```
cat files.txt | xargs ls -l | cut -c 23-30 | sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n/+/;ta' | bc
```

Comment: +1 for proving once and for all that there are uglier languages than perl :)

Answer (score 2):

I find myself reaching for `jq` for things like this, even when not working with JSON:

```
$ echo -e '1\n2\n3' | jq --slurp add
6
```

it's become a standard dependency for almost every script I've written recently.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe to gawk:

```
 cat files.txt | xargs ls -l | cut -c 23-30 | gawk 'BEGIN { sum = 0 } // { sum = sum + $0 } END { print sum }'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#
#       @(#) addup.sh 1.0 90/07/19
#
#       Copyright (C) <heh> SjB, 1990
#       Adds up a column (default=last) of numbers in a file.
#       95/05/16 updated to allow (999) negative style numbers.


case $1 in

-[0-9])

        COLUMN=`echo $1 | tr -d -`

        shift

;;

*)

        COLUMN="NF"

;;

esac

echo "Adding up column .. $COLUMN .. of file(s) .. $*"

nawk  ' OFMT="%.2f"                                       # 1 "%12.2f"

        { x = '$COLUMN'                                   # 2

          neg = index($x, "$")                            # 3

          if (neg > 0) X = gsub("\\$", "", $x)

          neg = index($x, ",")                            # 4

          if (neg > 1) X = gsub(",", "", $x)

          neg = index($x, "(")                            # 8 neg (123 & change

          if (neg > 0) X = gsub("\\(", "", $x)

          if (neg > 0) $x = (-1 * $x)                     # it to "-123.00"

          neg = index($x, "-")                            # 5

          if (neg > 1) $x = (-1 * $x)                     # 6

          t += $x                                         # 7

          print "x is <<<", $x+0, ">>> running balance:", t

        } ' $*


# 1.  set numeric format to eliminate rounding errors
# 1.1 had to reset numeric format from 12.2f to .2f 95/05/16
#     when a computed number is assigned to a variable ( $x = (-1 * $x) )
#     it causes $x to use the OFMT so -1.23 = "________-1.23" vs "-1.23"
#     and that causes my #5 (negative check) to not work correctly because
#     the index returns a number >1 and to the neg neg than becomes a positive
#     this only occurs if the number happened to b a "(" neg number
# 2.  find the field we want to add up (comes from the shell or defaults
#     to the last field "NF") in the file
# 3.  check for a dollar sign ($) in the number - if there get rid of it
#     so we may add it correctly - $12 $1$2 $1$2$ $$1$$2$$ all = 12
# 4.  check for a comma (,) in the number - if there get rid of it so we
#     may add it correctly - 1,2 12, 1,,2 1,,2,, all = 12   (,12=0)
# 5.  check for negative numbers
# 6.  if x is a negative number in the form 999- "make" it a recognized
#     number like -999 - if x is a negative number like -999 already
#     the test fails (y is not >1) and this "true" negative is not made
#     positive
# 7.  accumulate the total
# 8.  if x is a negative number in the form (999) "make it a recognized
#     number like -999
# * Note that a (-9) (neg neg number) returns a postive
# * Mite not work rite with all forms of all numbers using $-,+. etc. *
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to use....

```
echo "
1
2
3 " | sed -e 's,$, + p,g' | dc
```

they will show the sum of each line...

applying over this situation:

```
ls -ld $(< file.txt) | awk '{print $5}' | sed -e 's,$, + p,g' | dc
```

Total is the last value...

Answer (score 1):

Pure bash

```
total=0; for i in $(cat files.txt | xargs ls -l | cut -c 23-30); do 
total=$(( $total + $i )); done; echo $total
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the simplest solution to this is "expr" unix command:

```
s=0; 
for i in `cat files.txt | xargs ls -l | cut -c 23-30`
do
   s=`expr $s + $i`
done
echo $s
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sizes=( $(cat files.txt | xargs ls -l | cut -c 23-30) )
total=$(( $(IFS="+"; echo "${sizes[*]}") ))
```

Or you could just sum them as you read the sizes

```
declare -i total=0
while read x; total+=x; done < <( cat files.txt | xargs ls -l | cut -c 23-30 )
```

If you don't care about bite sizes and blocks is OK, then just

```
declare -i total=0
while read s junk; total+=s; done < <( cat files.txt | xargs ls -s )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have R, you can use:

```
> ... | Rscript -e 'print(sum(scan("stdin")));'
Read 4 items
[1] 2232320
```

---

Since I'm comfortable with R, I actually have several aliases for things like this so I can use them in `bash` without having to remember this syntax. For instance:

```
alias Rsum=$'Rscript -e \'print(sum(scan("stdin")));\''
```

which let's me do

```
> ... | Rsum
Read 4 items
[1] 2232320
```

Inspiration: [Is there a way to get the min, max, median, and average of a list of numbers in a single command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13775/148899)

Answer (score 0):

The most popular answer doesn't work right when the start of the pipe can produce 0 lines, because it ends up outputting nothing rather than 0.  You can get correct behavior by always adding 0:

`... | (cat && echo 0) | paste -sd+ - | bc`

Answer (score 0):

The - is not required for paste. The following will do as long as files.txt contains one or more valid file names:

```
<files.txt xargs stat -c %s | paste -sd+ | bc
```

cat is not required to insert 0 in case there is no file. Without a pipe, perhaps more convenient in a script, you could use:

```
(xargs -a files.txt stat -c %s || echo 0) | paste -sd+ | bc
```