# How can I count all the lines of code in a directory recursively?

Tags: bash, shell

We've got a PHP application and want to count all the lines of code under a specific directory and its subdirectories.

We don't need to ignore comments, as we're just trying to get a rough idea.

```
wc -l *.php
```

That command works great for a given directory, but it ignores subdirectories. I was thinking the following comment might work, but it is returning 74, which is definitely not the case...

```
find . -name '*.php' | wc -l
```

What's the correct syntax to feed in all the files from a directory resursively?

Answer (score 3251, accepted):

**Try:**

```
find . -name '*.php' | xargs wc -l
```

or (when file names include special characters such as spaces)

```
find . -name '*.php' | sed 's/.*/"&"/' | xargs  wc -l
```

**[The SLOCCount tool](https://dwheeler.com/sloccount/)** may help as well.

It will give an accurate source lines of code count for whatever
hierarchy you point it at, as well as some additional stats.

**Sorted output:**

`find . -name '*.php' | xargs wc -l | sort -nr`

Comment: http://cloc.sourceforge.net/ might be worth looking as an alternative to sloccount (more languages but less informations)

Comment: with include files also: `find . -name '*.php' -o -name '*.inc' | xargs wc -l`

Comment: This will print more than one number when there are many files (because `wc` will be run multiple times. Also doesn't handle many special file names.

Comment: Is there a way to exclude a directory (e.g ./tests) from the count?

Comment: This should exclude blank lines  `$ find . -name '*.php' | xargs cat | awk '/[a-zA-Z0-9]/ {i++} END{print i}'`

Comment: @idober: `find . -name "*.php" -not -path "./tests*" | xargs wc -l`

Comment: pay attention. wc counts line ending codes, not lines. I described this later in this post. use grep ^ , not wc -l . If you need, grep can filter out with counting lines that have only white chars.

Comment: If a directory name contains any spaces... the above command fails!!

Comment: This should be a work-around for that: `find . -name '*.php' | awk '{gsub(" ","\\ ", $0);print $0}' |xargs wc -l`

Comment: As an aside, xargs isn't available natively in the Windows shell, but if you happen to have git installed then this solution works great in git bash.

Comment: @nitish712 find and xargs handle the space issue using `-print0` and `-0` options, respectively. So you can try something like `find . -name "*.php" -print0 | xargs -0 wc -l`

Comment: @l0b0 does that mean the last total will be inaccurate or just displayed multiple times?

Comment: @tieTYT It will be inaccurate, because it will chunk files together and count the lines in each chunk, without summarising.

Comment: @l0b0 ah, then (no offense intended) this seems like an inferior solution compared to Shizzmo's

Comment: @tieTYT Technically speaking, yes, but it's POSIX compatible (`-print0` is not), shorter and it'll work unless you have very many files.

Comment: For iOS app: `find . -name '*.[h|m|plist]' | xargs wc -l`

Comment: `sudo apt-get install sloccount` on Ubuntu. Then `$ sloccount mydir`

Comment: @pyeleven how do I exclude multiple folders?

Comment: @l0b0 for a big number of files it should work with a `cat` inbetween: `find . -name '*.php' | xargs cat | wc -l`

Comment: I am sorry but i would like to understand why would using xargs work and without xargs it would not work

Comment: @idober [-prune](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/find.1.html), e.g. `find . -name tests -prune -o -type f -name '*.php' | xargs wc -l`

Comment: How would I write a function to shortcut this command in bash? In my .bash_profile I currently have: function lncnt { find . -name $1 | xargs wc -l; } but when I run the command it only counts lines for the first file alphabetically.

Comment: What is the difference between piping the output and using xargs?

Comment: Following up on @vcardillo 's comment, if you are on OSX and have Homebrew installed, you can run: `brew install sloccount` and then `sloccount mydir`

Comment: BTW it seems like cloc has now moved to [github](https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc)

Comment: I know question is about PHP, but i bet people are coming for other languages too. To simpler copy-paste experiences here are couple lines. JS: `find . -name '*.js' | xargs wc -l`  CSS: `find . -name '*.css' | xargs wc -l` JSX: `find . -name '*.jsx' | xargs wc -l`

Comment: This was not accurate for me, compare the results of this to Michael Wild. For me, Michael Wild's command gave the accurate result.

Comment: I'm surprised there's no simple solution here for the "path has a space in it" problem. This is what I ended up with: `find . -name '*.swift' -exec wc -l {} \+`. The `+` at the end means that `wc` is run just once, which is fast!

Comment: because of command line limits this can generate multiple totals which need to be added, try using 
| xargs cat | wc -l to overcome that.

Comment: At least on my machine (Ubuntu 18.04), I have `sort (GNU coreutils) 8.28` which doesn't do what expected with `find . -name '*.php' | xargs wc -l | sort`, because it sorts `wc`'s output as text. In order to fix that I had to use `sort -n` instead. Maybe other versions of `sort` behave differently.

Comment: `xargs` hasn't been necessary for a few decades now. Am I wrong?

Comment: Is it possible to do this for all text files, not just ones with a specific extension?

Comment: `type -file` or whatever might be nice...

Answer (score 586):

You can use the [`cloc`](https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc) utility which is built for this exact purpose. It reports each the amount of lines in each language, together with how many of them are comments, etc. CLOC is available on Linux, Mac and Windows.

Usage and output example:

```
$ cloc --exclude-lang=DTD,Lua,make,Python .
    2570 text files.
    2200 unique files.
    8654 files ignored.

http://cloc.sourceforge.net v 1.53  T=8.0 s (202.4 files/s, 99198.6 lines/s)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Language                     files          blank        comment           code
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
JavaScript                    1506          77848         212000         366495
CSS                             56           9671          20147          87695
HTML                            51           1409            151           7480
XML                              6           3088           1383           6222
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SUM:                          1619          92016         233681         467892
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: That's a lovely tool that runs nice and quickly giving useful stats at the end. Love it.

Comment: Note that you can run Unix commands on Windows using cygwin (or other similar ports/environments). To me, having this kind of access so extremely useful, it's a necessity. A unix command line is magical. I especially like perl and regular expressions.

Comment: CLOC and SLOCCount work fine on mid 2015 macbook. Note their numbers are close but not exactly the same for 127k Java Android project. Also note the iOS equivalent had 2x the LoC; so, the "cost" metric in SLOCCount might be off (or maybe iOS dev make 2x what Android dev make. :-)

Comment: Would you consider editing the beginning of this question to make it clear that `cloc` is cross-platform since it's just a Perl script?

Comment: Just perfect, works fine in Windows bash as well of course.

Comment: I didn't have that tool installed, but with Node installed you can go `npx cloc myApp` to run it without installing globally

Comment: Note, that `cloc` is not available as a cygwin package. You have to, instead, download the exe version here https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc. You can then run `cloc` in your cygwin shell provided you convert unix path string to windowish format.

Comment: Only issue is, `cloc` is, (being written in Perl) **excruciatingly slow** compared to `wc`.

Comment: I like CLOC but I'd love to see a word count feature.

Comment: @CurtisYallop Nowadays [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) would be preferable instead of Cygwin. [Apparently its package repo has `cloc` too!](https://packages.msys2.org/base/cloc)

Answer (score 564):

For another one-liner:

```
( find ./ -name '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 cat ) | wc -l
```

It works on names with spaces and only outputs one number.

Comment: +1 ditto...searched forever...all the other "find" commands only returned the # of actual files....the -print0 stuff here got the actual line count for me!!! thanks!

Comment: Best solution I've found.  I parameterized the path and filetype and added this code to a script on my path.  I plan to use it frequently.

Comment: Why are you thanked for `print0`? What does that mean?

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun - see `man find` .. print0 with xargs -0 lets you operate on files that have spaces or other weird characters in their name

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun - also, the -0 in xargs corresponds to the print0, it's kind of encoding/decoding to handle the spaces.

Comment: Is there any way to exclude specific subdirectories with this?

Comment: If you need more than one name filter, I've found that (at least with the MSYSGit version of find), you need extra parens:

`( find . \( -name '*.h' -o -name '*.cpp' \) -print0 | xargs -0 cat ) | wc -l`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in my opinion since it gives a single number (something the question implied).

Comment: I love how fast this command is on a journaled file system (instant)

Comment: @Ronedog: the reason it works is because of the "cat" command that xargs is executing.  The -print0 just means that it uses null characters to separate the filenames that are being passed to xargs so that spaces will be handled properly.

Comment: @DesignbyAdrian: Journaling helps with crash recovery, not speed.  It is likely you are seeing good performance due to caching or a very fast HDD.

Comment: @Shizzmo your solution does not exclude blank lines.

Comment: Errors will come if there are recursive directories as it will try to cat out the directories as well... or worse in some linux system cat of directory will return the files within so in total number of lines, the count of number of files will be added

Comment: This one, unlike the accepted answer, works for directory names containing spaces.

Comment: Similarly, I dropped the cat to print out file names and this achieved the same total output for me on OS X: `find . -name '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 wc -l`

Comment: This approach does not work on real projects. you'd run out of memory

Comment: `( find ./ -name '*.java' -print0 | xargs -0 cat | sed '/^\s*$/d' ) | wc -l`  : adding `sed '/^\s*$/d'` will ignore all the blank lines in file.

Comment: @Wisienkas Not true, it uses next to no memory. Each file is streamed to `wc -l` . It is not every file being catted together then sent to `wc`. That is why we use xargs here. Remember, these things were made a long time ago when people had MUCH less memory.

Comment: for counting java code comments: find ./ -name '*.java' -print0 | xargs -0 cat | grep '* ' | wc -l

Answer (score 456):

If using a decently recent version of Bash (or ZSH), it's much simpler:

```
wc -l **/*.php
```

In the Bash shell this requires the `globstar` option to be set, otherwise the `**` glob-operator is not recursive. To enable this setting, issue

```
shopt -s globstar
```

To make this permanent, add it to one of the initialization files (`~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile` etc.).

Comment: I am upvoting this for simplicity, however I just want to point out that it doesn't appear to search the directories recursively, it only checks the subdirectories of the current directory.  This is on SL6.3.

Comment: That depends on your shell and the options you have set. Bash requires [`globstar` to be set](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) for this to work.

Comment: @MichaelWild, and what if I need more lines of code than this can handle? It is returning a very low value for the Linux Kernel...

Comment: @PeterSenna, with the current 3.9.8 kernel archive, the command `wc -l **/*.[ch]` finds a total of 15195373 lines. Not sure whether you consider that to be a "very low value". Again, you need to make sure that you have `globstar` enabled in Bash. You can check with `shopt globstar`. To enable it explicitly, do `shopt -s globstar`.

Comment: @Sheena Have you actually read the comments? If you enable the `gobstart` shell option, it *is* recursive.

Comment: @MichaelWild This is a good solution, but it will still overflow `ARG_MAX` if you have a large number of `.php` files, since `wc` is not builtin.

Comment: It seems the result is larger than the accepted answer. Anyone know why?

Comment: @AlbertSamuel No, you'd need to compare the list of files produced by both methods. My method has the problem of not working for large numbers of files, as mentioned by @BroSlow. The accepted answer will fail if the paths produced by `find` contain spaces. That could be fixed by using `print0` and `--null` with the `find` and `xargs` calls, respectively.

Comment: If you are on a Mac you have to install a recent version of Bash to set globstar in shopt . By default MacOS has version 3.2 installed. But globstar is available from version 4. Another issue you might encounter is that your IDE (in my case PhpStorm) is still using the old (MacOS' native) Bash version. So you have to change the "Shell Path" in Preferences>Tools>Terminal from `/bin/bash` to `/usr/local/bin/bash` or whatever the path to the new Bash version is

Comment: If you want to include multiple file types (via extensions) you can extend this and use bash expansion:
```bash
wc -l **/*.{py,yml,md,js,html}
```

Answer (score 117):

On Unix-like systems, there is a tool called `cloc` which provides code statistics.

I ran in on a random directory in our code base it says:

```
      59 text files.
      56 unique files.
       5 files ignored.

http://cloc.sourceforge.net v 1.53  T=0.5 s (108.0 files/s, 50180.0 lines/s)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Language                     files          blank        comment           code
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C                               36           3060           1431          16359
C/C++ Header                    16            689            393           3032
make                             1             17              9             54
Teamcenter def                   1             10              0             36
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SUM:                            54           3776           1833          19481
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I like it. cloc is really neat. But what means that name?

Comment: It's on Windows now too! Assuming you've got [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/): `choco install cloc`

Comment: @Manoel: I guess it means “count lines of code”

Answer (score 51):

You didn't specify how many files are there or what is the desired output.

This may be what you are looking for:

```
find . -name '*.php' | xargs wc -l
```

Comment: This will work, as long as there are not too many files : if there are a lot of files, you will get several lines as a result (xargs will split the files list in several sub-lists)

Comment: ah, yes. That's why I said He didn't specify how many files are there. My version is easier to remember, but Shin's version is better if You have more than a few files. I'm voting it up.

Comment: I needed to adapt this for use in a function, where single quotes are too restrictive:  
 
`go () { 
    mkdir /tmp/go; 
    [[ -f ./"$1" ]] && mv ./"$1" /tmp/go; 
    (find ./ -type f -name "$*" -print0 | xargs -0 cat ) | wc -l; wc -l /tmp/go/*; 
    mv /tmp/go/* . 
}` 

Results were close to slocount for `*.py`, but it didn't know `*.js`, `*.html`.

Answer (score 43):

Yet another variation :)

```
$ find . -name '*.php' | xargs cat | wc -l
```

This will give the total sum, instead of file-by-file.

Add `.` after `find` to make it work.

Comment: At least in cygwin, I had better results with: `$ find -name \*\.php -print0 | xargs -0 cat | wc -l`

Comment: on Darwin, this just gives a grand total: `find . -name '*.php' | xargs cat | wc -l` ... whereas this gives  file-by-file and a grand total: `find . -name '*.php' | xargs wc -l`

Answer (score 35):

Use [find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_(Unix))'s `-exec` and `awk`. Here we go:

```
find . -type f -exec wc -l {} \; | awk '{ SUM += $0} END { print SUM }'
```

This snippet finds for all files (`-type f`). To find by file extension, use `-name`:

```
find . -name '*.py' -exec wc -l '{}' \; | awk '{ SUM += $0; } END { print SUM; }'
```

Comment: Functionally, this works perfectly, but on large listing (linux source) it is really slow because it's starting a wc process for each file instead of 1 wc process for all the files. I timed it at 31 seconds using this method compared to 1.5 seconds using `find . -name '*.c' -print0 |xargs -0 wc -l`. That said, this faster method (at least on OS X), ends up printing "total" several times so some additional filtering is required to get a proper total (I posted details in my answer).

Comment: This has the benefit of working for an unlimited number of files.  Well done!

Comment: this is far better solution once working with large amount of GB and files. doing one `wc` on a form of a `cat` is slow because the system first must process all GB to start counting the lines (tested with 200GB of jsons, 12k files). doing `wc` first then counting the result is far faster

Comment: @DougRichardson, you could consider this instead:
`find . -type f -exec wc -l {} \+` or  `find . -name '*.py' -type f -exec wc -l {} \+`

which prints a total at the end of the output. If all you're interested in is the total, then you could go a bit further and use `tail`:

`find . -type f -exec wc -l {} \+ | tail -1` or `find . -name '*.py' -type f -exec wc -l {} \+ | tail -1`

Answer (score 34):

The tool [Tokei](https://github.com/XAMPPRocky/tokei) displays statistics about code in a directory. Tokei will show the number of files, total lines within those files and code, comments, and blanks grouped by language. Tokei is also available on Mac, Linux, and Windows.

An example of the output of Tokei is as follows:

```
$ tokei
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Language            Files        Lines         Code     Comments       Blanks
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 CSS                     2           12           12            0            0
 JavaScript              1          435          404            0           31
 JSON                    3          178          178            0            0
 Markdown                1            9            9            0            0
 Rust                   10          408          259           84           65
 TOML                    3           69           41           17           11
 YAML                    1           30           25            0            5
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Total                  21         1141          928          101          112
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Tokei can be installed by following [the instructions on the README file in the repository](https://github.com/XAMPPRocky/tokei/blob/master/README.md#installation).

Comment: Great tool, thanks.

Comment: But how to count code recursively inside directories using `tokei` which question is about?

Answer (score 28):

More common and simple as for me, suppose you need to count files of different name extensions (say, also natives):

```
wc $(find . -type f | egrep "\.(h|c|cpp|php|cc)" )
```

Comment: this does not do quite what you think.
find . -name '*.[am]' is identical to find . -name '*.[a|m]'

both will find all files that ends with .m or .a

Comment: but the second will also find files ending in .| , if any.  So [h|c|cpp|php|cc] ends up being the same as [hcp|] .

Comment: backticks are deprecated, prefer `$()`

Comment: This works under Cygwin. Of course, the "C:\" drive has to follow the cygwin convention, like for example:    wc $(find /cygdrive/c//SomeWindowsFolderj/ -type f | egrep "\.(h|c|cpp|php|cc)" )

Answer (score 25):

**POSIX**

Unlike most other answers here, these work on any POSIX system, for any number of files, and with any file names (except where noted).

---

Lines in each file:

```
find . -name '*.php' -type f -exec wc -l {} \;
# faster, but includes total at end if there are multiple files
find . -name '*.php' -type f -exec wc -l {} +
```

Lines in each file, sorted by file path

```
find . -name '*.php' -type f | sort | xargs -L1 wc -l
# for files with spaces or newlines, use the non-standard sort -z
find . -name '*.php' -type f -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 -L1 wc -l
```

Lines in each file, sorted by number of lines, descending

```
find . -name '*.php' -type f -exec wc -l {} \; | sort -nr
# faster, but includes total at end if there are multiple files
find . -name '*.php' -type f -exec wc -l {} + | sort -nr
```

Total lines in all files

```
find . -name '*.php' -type f -exec cat {} + | wc -l
```

Answer (score 24):

There is a little tool called [**sloccount**](https://dwheeler.com/sloccount/) to count the lines of code in a directory.

It should be noted that it does more than you want as it ignores empty lines/comments, groups the results per programming language and calculates some statistics.

Comment: For windows, [LocMetrics](http://www.locmetrics.com/) do the job

Comment: A repeat of the accepted answer (though posted at the same time).

Answer (score 15):

You want a simple `for` loop:

```
total_count=0
for file in $(find . -name *.php -print)
do
    count=$(wc -l $file)
    let total_count+=count
done
echo "$total_count"
```

Comment: isn't this overkill compared to the answers that suggest `xargs`?

Comment: No, Nathan. The xargs answers won't necessarily print the count as a single number. It may just print a bunch of subtotals.

Comment: what will this program do if file names contain spaces? What about newlines? ;-)

Comment: If your file names contain new lines, I'd say you have bigger problems.

Comment: @ennuikiller Number of issues with this, first of all it will break on files with whitespaces. Setting `IFS=$'\n'` before the loop would at least fix it for all but files with newlines in their names. Second, you're not quoting `'*.php'`, so it will get expanded by the shell and not `find`, and ergo won't actually find any of the php files in subdirectories. Also the `-print` is redundant, since it's implied in the absence of other actions.

Comment: I would change line 4 to:
count=$(wc -l < $file)
in order to suppress the syntax errors, otherwise this works as an alternative although I agree it's a bit overkill.

Answer (score 13):

For sources only:

```
wc `find`
```

To filter, just use [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep):

```
wc `find | grep .php$`
```

Answer (score 12):

A straightforward one that will be fast, will use all the search/filtering power of `find`, not fail when there are too many files (number arguments overflow), work fine with files with funny symbols in their name, without using `xargs`, and will not launch a uselessly high number of external commands (thanks to `+` for `find`'s `-exec`). Here you go:

```
find . -name '*.php' -type f -exec cat -- {} + | wc -l
```

Comment: I was about to post a variant of this myself (with `\;` instead of `+` as I wasn't aware of it), this answer should be the correct answer.

Comment: I did ( find . -type f -exec cat {} \; |wc -l ) then I saw this. Just wondering what '--' and '+' in this solution mean and the difference to my version regarding number of external commands.

Comment: @grenix: your version will spawn a new `cat` for each file found, whereas the `\+` version will give all the files found to `cat` in one call. The `--` is to mark the end of options (it's a bit unnecessary here).

Comment: what I do not understand is how this avoids number of arguments overflow.  If I do 'find . -type f -exec cat -- {} + |more' and ' ps aux|grep "cat "' in another terminal I get somthing like '...  66128  0.0  0.0   7940  2020 pts/10   S+   13:45   0:00 cat -- ./file1 ./file2 ...'

Answer (score 11):

None of the answers so far gets at the problem of filenames with spaces.

Additionally, all that use `xargs` are subject to fail if the total length of paths in the tree exceeds the shell environment size limit (defaults to a few megabytes in Linux).

Here is one that fixes these problems in a pretty direct manner. The subshell takes care of files with spaces. The `awk` totals the stream of individual file `wc` outputs, so it ought never to run out of space. It also restricts the `exec` to files only (skipping directories):

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec bash -c 'wc -l "$0"' {} \; | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
```

Answer (score 10):

`bash` tools are always nice to use, but for this purpose it seems to be more efficient to just use a tool that does that. I played with some of the main ones as of 2022, namely [cloc (perl)](https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc),  [gocloc (go)](https://github.com/hhatto/gocloc), [pygount (python)](https://github.com/roskakori/pygount).

Got various results without tweaking them too much.
Seems the most accurate and blazingly fast is `gocloc`.

Example on a small laravel project with a vue frontend:

### gocloc

```
$ ~/go/bin/gocloc /home/jmeyo/project/sequasa
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Language                     files          blank        comment           code
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSON                             5              0              0          16800
Vue                             96           1181            137           8993
JavaScript                      37            999            454           7604
PHP                            228           1493           2622           7290
CSS                              2            157             44            877
Sass                             5             72            426            466
XML                             11              0              2            362
Markdown                         2             45              0            111
YAML                             1              0              0             13
Plain Text                       1              0              0              2
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                          388           3947           3685          42518
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### cloc

```
$ cloc /home/jmeyo/project/sequasa
     450 text files.
     433 unique files.                                          
      40 files ignored.

github.com/AlDanial/cloc v 1.90  T=0.24 s (1709.7 files/s, 211837.9 lines/s)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Language                     files          blank        comment           code
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSON                             5              0              0          16800
Vuejs Component                 95           1181            370           8760
JavaScript                      37            999            371           7687
PHP                            180           1313           2600           5321
Blade                           48            180            187           1804
SVG                             27              0              0           1273
CSS                              2            157             44            877
XML                             12              0              2            522
Sass                             5             72            418            474
Markdown                         2             45              0            111
YAML                             4             11             37             53
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SUM:                           417           3958           4029          43682
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### pygcount

```
$ pygount --format=summary /home/jmeyo/project/sequasa
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━┓
┃ Language      ┃ Files ┃     % ┃  Code ┃     % ┃ Comment ┃    % ┃
┡━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━┩
│ JSON          │     5 │   1.0 │ 12760 │  76.0 │       0 │  0.0 │
│ PHP           │   182 │  37.1 │  4052 │  43.8 │    1288 │ 13.9 │
│ JavaScript    │    37 │   7.5 │  3654 │  40.4 │     377 │  4.2 │
│ XML+PHP       │    43 │   8.8 │  1696 │  89.6 │      39 │  2.1 │
│ CSS+Lasso     │     2 │   0.4 │   702 │  65.2 │      44 │  4.1 │
│ SCSS          │     5 │   1.0 │   368 │  38.2 │     419 │ 43.5 │
│ HTML+PHP      │     2 │   0.4 │   171 │  85.5 │       0 │  0.0 │
│ Markdown      │     2 │   0.4 │    86 │  55.1 │       4 │  2.6 │
│ XML           │     1 │   0.2 │    29 │  93.5 │       2 │  6.5 │
│ Text only     │     1 │   0.2 │     2 │ 100.0 │       0 │  0.0 │
│ __unknown__   │   132 │  26.9 │     0 │   0.0 │       0 │  0.0 │
│ __empty__     │     6 │   1.2 │     0 │   0.0 │       0 │  0.0 │
│ __duplicate__ │     6 │   1.2 │     0 │   0.0 │       0 │  0.0 │
│ __binary__    │    67 │  13.6 │     0 │   0.0 │       0 │  0.0 │
├───────────────┼───────┼───────┼───────┼───────┼─────────┼──────┤
│ Sum           │   491 │ 100.0 │ 23520 │  59.7 │    2173 │  5.5 │
└───────────────┴───────┴───────┴───────┴───────┴─────────┴──────┘
```

Results are mixed, the closest to the reality seems to be the `gocloc` one, and is also by far the fastest:

- cloc: 0m0.430s
- gocloc: 0m0.059s
- pygcount: 0m39.980s

Answer (score 9):

I know the question is tagged as [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), but it seems that the problem you're trying to solve is also PHP related.

Sebastian Bergmann wrote a tool called [PHPLOC](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phploc) that does what you want and on top of that provides you with an overview of a project's complexity. This is an example of its report:

```
Size
  Lines of Code (LOC)                            29047
  Comment Lines of Code (CLOC)                   14022 (48.27%)
  Non-Comment Lines of Code (NCLOC)              15025 (51.73%)
  Logical Lines of Code (LLOC)                    3484 (11.99%)
    Classes                                       3314 (95.12%)
      Average Class Length                          29
      Average Method Length                          4
    Functions                                      153 (4.39%)
      Average Function Length                        1
    Not in classes or functions                     17 (0.49%)

Complexity
  Cyclomatic Complexity / LLOC                    0.51
  Cyclomatic Complexity / Number of Methods       3.37
```

As you can see, the information provided is a lot more useful from the perspective of a developer, because it can roughly tell you how complex a project is before you start working with it.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to keep it simple, cut out the middleman and just call `wc` with all the filenames:

```
wc -l `find . -name "*.php"`
```

Or in the modern syntax:

```
wc -l $(find . -name "*.php")
```

This works as long as there are no spaces in any of the directory names or filenames. And as long as you don't have tens of thousands of files (modern shells support really long command lines). Your project has 74 files, so you've got plenty of room to grow.

Comment: I like this one! If you are in hybrid C/C++ environment: ```wc -l `find . -type f \( -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.c" -o -name "*.h" \) -print` ```

Answer (score 7):

> WC -L  ?  better use GREP -C ^

`wc -l`? **Wrong!**

The [wc](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wc) command counts new lines codes, **not** lines! When the last line in the file does not end with new line code, **this will not be counted!**

If you still want count lines, use  **grep -c ^**. Full example:

```
# This example prints line count for all found files
total=0
find /path -type f -name "*.php" | while read FILE; do
     # You see, use 'grep' instead of 'wc'! for properly counting
     count=$(grep -c ^ < "$FILE")
     echo "$FILE has $count lines"
     let total=total+count #in bash, you can convert this for another shell
done
echo TOTAL LINES COUNTED:  $total
```

Finally, watch out for the `wc -l` trap **(counts enters, not lines!!!)**

Comment: Please read the [POSIX definition of a line](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_205). With `grep -c ^` you're counting the number of [incomplete lines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_194), and such incomplete lines cannot appear in a [text file](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_392).

Comment: I know it. In practice only last line can be incomplete because it hasn't got EOL. Idea is counting all lines including incomplete one. It is very frequent mistake, counting only complete lines. after counting we are thinking "why I missed last line???". This is answer why, and recipe how to do it properly.

Comment: Or, if you want a one liner: `find -type f -name '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -ch ^ | paste -sd+ - | bc`  See here for alternatives to `bc`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/926069/2400328

Answer (score 5):

Giving out the longest files first (ie. maybe these long files need some refactoring love?), and excluding some vendor directories:

```
 find . -name '*.php' | xargs wc -l | sort -nr | egrep -v "libs|tmp|tests|vendor" | less
```

Comment: Excluding directories is important in projects in which there's generated code or files copied on the build process

Answer (score 5):

For **Windows**, an easy-and-quick tool is **[LocMetrics](http://www.locmetrics.com)**.

Comment: It's pretty unlikely OP is on Windows if they're using bash.

Comment: @VanessaMcHale question title and description both don't clearly require unix-only solution. So Windows based solution is acceptable. Also Google pointed me to this page when I was looking for similar solution.

Comment: This comment helped me. I tried this and it works well.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a utility called `codel` ([link](https://github.com/VoIlAlex/codel)). It's a simple Python module to count lines with colorful formatting.

#### Installation

```sh
pip install codel
```

#### Usage

To count lines of C++ files (with `.cpp` and `.h` extensions), use:

```sh
codel count -e .cpp .h
```

You can also ignore some files/folder with the .gitignore format:

```sh
codel count -e .py -i tests/**
```

It will ignore all the files in the `tests/` folder.

The output looks like:

[image: Long output]

You also can shorten the output with the `-s` flag. It will hide the information of each file and show only information about each extension. The example is below:

[image: Short output]

Comment: Is there a way to do this for all text files, not just specific extensions?

Comment: @AaronFranke By now there is no way.

Answer (score 4):

Very simply:

```
find /path -type f -name "*.php" | while read FILE
do
    count=$(wc -l < $FILE)
    echo "$FILE has $count lines"
done
```

Comment: it will fail if there is a space or a newline in one of the filenames

Answer (score 4):

If you want your results sorted by number of lines, you can just add `| sort` or `| sort -r` (`-r` for descending order) to the first answer, like so:

```
find . -name '*.php' | xargs wc -l | sort -r
```

Comment: Since the output of `xargs wc -l` is numeric, one would actually need to use `sort -n` or `sort -nr`.

Answer (score 4):

Something different:

```
wc -l `tree -if --noreport | grep -e'\.php$'`
```

This works out fine, but you need to have at least one `*.php` file in the current folder or one of its subfolders, or else [`wc`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wc) stalls.

Comment: may also overflow ARG_MAX

Answer (score 4):

It’s very easy with [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) (zsh) globs:

```
wc -l ./**/*.php
```

If you are using Bash, you just need to upgrade. There is absolutely no reason to use Bash.

Answer (score 4):

If the files are too many, better to just look for the total line count.

```
find . -name '*.php' | xargs wc -l | grep -i ' total' | awk '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need just the total number of lines in, let's say, your PHP files, you can use very simple one line command even under Windows if you have GnuWin32 installed. Like this:

```
cat `/gnuwin32/bin/find.exe . -name *.php` | wc -l
```

You need to specify where exactly is the find.exe otherwise the Windows provided [FIND.EXE](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html) (from the old DOS-like commands) will be executed, since it is probably before the GnuWin32 in the environment PATH and has different parameters and results.

Please note that in the command above you should use back-quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: In the example above I'm using the bash for windows instead of the cmd.exe that's why there are forward slashes "/" and not back slashes "\".

Answer (score 3):

On OS X at least, the find+xarg+wc commands listed in some of the other answers prints "total" several times on large listings, and there is no complete total given. I was able to get a single total for .c files using the following command:

`find . -name '*.c' -print0 |xargs -0 wc -l|grep -v total|awk '{ sum += $1; } END { print "SUM: " sum; }'`

Comment: Instead of `grep -v total` you can use `grep total` - which will sum the intermediate sums given by `wc`. It doesn't make sense to re-calculate intermediate sums since `wc` already did it.

Answer (score 3):

While I like the scripts, I prefer this one as it also shows a per-file summary as long as a total:

```
wc -l `find . -name "*.php"`
```

Comment: Re *"...as long as a total..."*: Don't you mean *"...as well as a total..."*?

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to check on multiple file types and was to lazy to calculate the total by hand. So I use this now to get the total in one go.

```
find . -name '*.js' -or -name '*.php' | xargs wc -l | grep 'total'  | awk '{ SUM += $1; print $1} END { print "Total text lines in PHP and JS",SUM }'
```

> 79351 
> 15318 
> Total text lines in PHP and JS 94669

This allows you to chain multiple extension types you wish to filter on. Just add them in the `-name '*.js' -or -name '*.php'` part, and possibly modify the otuput message to your liking.

Comment: good hack with awk and no need to install additional tools, thank you! Also, if you want to skip the folders and don't specify file extensions (count in all files), then `-type f` will help here: `find . -type f | xargs wc -l | grep 'total'  | awk '{ SUM += $1; print $1} END { print "Total text lines: ",SUM }'`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need all these complicated and hard to remember commands. You just need a [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) tool called **line-counter**.

**A quick overview**

This is how you get the tool

```
$ pip install line-counter
```

Use the `line` command to get the file count and line count under current directory (recursively):

```
$ line
Search in /Users/Morgan/Documents/Example/
file count: 4
line count: 839
```

If you want more detail, just use `line -d`.

```
$ line -d
Search in /Users/Morgan/Documents/Example/
Dir A/file C.c                                             72
Dir A/file D.py                                           268
file A.py                                                 467
file B.c                                                   32
file count: 4
line count: 839
```

And the best part of this tool is, you can add a `.gitignore`-like configuration file to it. You can set up rules to select or ignore what kind of files to count just like what you do in '.gitignore'.

More description and usage is here: https://github.com/MorganZhang100/line-counter

Answer (score 3):

If you're on Linux (and I take it you are), I recommend my tool [polyglot](http://github.com/vmchale/polyglot). It is dramatically faster than either `sloccount` or `cloc` and it is more featureful than `sloccount`.

You can invoke it with

```
poly .
```

or

```
poly
```

so it's much more user-friendly than some convoluted Bash script.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to [Shizzmo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1359246/315024), but uglier and more accurate. If you're using it often, modify it to suit and put it in a script.

This example:

1. Properly excludes paths that aren't your code (not traversed at all by `find`)
2. Filters out compound extensions and other files you wish to ignore
3. Only includes actual files of the types you specify
4. Ignores blank lines
5. Gives a single number as a total

```sh
find . \! \( \( -path ./lib -o -path ./node_modules -o -path ./vendor -o -path ./any/other/path/to/skip -o -wholename ./not/this/specific/file.php -o -name '*.min.js' -o -name '*.min.css' \) -prune \) -type f \( -name '*.php' -o -name '*.inc' -o -name '*.js' -o -name '*.scss' -o -name '*.css' \) -print0 | xargs -0 cat | grep -vcE '^[[:space:]]*$'
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this for all text files, not just ones with specific extensions?

Comment: @AaronFranke That should be a lot easier, try: `grep -rvcIE '^[[:space:]]*$'` The `r` flag means search recursively, and the `I` flag means ignore binary files.

Answer (score 2):

```
$cd directory
$wc -l* | sort -nr
```

Answer (score 2):

I used this inline-script that I launch from on a source project's directory:

```
 for i in $(find . -type f); do rowline=$(wc -l $i | cut -f1 -d" "); file=$(wc -l $i | cut -f2 -d" "); lines=$((lines + rowline)); echo "Lines["$lines"] " $file "has "$rowline"rows."; done && unset lines
```

That produces this output:

```
Lines[75]  ./Db.h has 75rows.
Lines[143]  ./Db.cpp has 68rows.
Lines[170]  ./main.cpp has 27rows.
Lines[294]  ./Sqlite.cpp has 124rows.
Lines[349]  ./Sqlite.h has 55rows.
Lines[445]  ./Table.cpp has 96rows.
Lines[480]  ./DbError.cpp has 35rows.
Lines[521]  ./DbError.h has 41rows.
Lines[627]  ./QueryResult.cpp has 106rows.
Lines[717]  ./QueryResult.h has 90rows.
Lines[828]  ./Table.h has 111rows.
```

Answer (score 2):

Excluding blank lines:

```
find . -name "*.php" | xargs grep -v -c '^$' | awk 'BEGIN {FS=":"} { $cnt = $cnt + $2} END {print $cnt}'
```

Including blank lines:

```
find . -name "*.php" | xargs wc -l
```

Answer (score 2):

First change the directory to which you want to know the number of lines.

For example, if I want to know the number of lines in all files of a directory named *sample*, give `$cd sample`.

Then try the command `$wc -l *`. This will return the number of lines for each file and also the total number of lines in the entire directory at the end.

Answer (score 2):

I do it like this:

Here is the *lineCount.c* file implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int getLinesFromFile(const char*);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   int total_lines = 0;
   for(int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
       total_lines += getLinesFromFile(argv[i]); // *argv is a char*
   }

   printf("You have a total of %d lines in all your file(s)\n",    total_lines);
   return 0;
}


int getLinesFromFile(const char* file_name) {
    int lines = 0;
    FILE* file;
    file = fopen(file_name, "r");
    char c = ' ';
    while((c = getc(file)) != EOF)
        if(c == '\n')
            ++lines;
    fclose(file);
    return lines;
}
```

Now open the command line and type `gcc lineCount.c`. Then type `./a.out *.txt`.

This will display the total lines of files ending with .txt in your directory.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a flexible one using older Python (works in at least Python 2.6) incorporating [Shizzmo's lovely one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358540/how-can-i-count-all-the-lines-of-code-in-a-directory-recursively/1359246#1359246). Just fill in the `types` list with the filetypes you want counted in the source folder, and let it fly:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess

rcmd = "( find ./ -name '*.%s' -print0 | xargs -0 cat ) | wc -l"
types = ['c','cpp','h','txt']

sum = 0
for el in types:
    cmd = rcmd % (el)
    p = subprocess.Popen([cmd],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
    out = p.stdout.read().strip()
    print "*.%s: %s" % (el,out)
    sum += int(out)
print "sum: %d" % (sum)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to count LOC you have written, you may need to exclude some files.

For a [Django](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29) project, you may want to ignore the `migrations` and `static` folders. For a JavaScript project, you may exclude all pictures or all fonts.

```
find . \( -path '*/migrations' -o -path '*/.git' -o -path '*/.vscode' -o -path '*/fonts' -o -path '*.png' -o -path '*.jpg' -o -path '*/.github' -o -path '*/static' \) -prune -o -type f -exec cat {} + | wc -l
```

Usage here is as follows:

*/folder_name 
*/.file_extension

To list the files, modify the latter part of the command:

```
find . \( -path '*/migrations' -o -path '*/.git' -o -path '*/.vscode' -o -path '*/fonts' -o -path '*.png' -o -path '*.jpg' -o -path '*/.github' -o -path '*/static' \) -prune -o --print
```

Answer (score 2):

On Windows PowerShell try this:

```
dir -Recurse *.php | Get-Content | Measure-Object -Line
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to list the lines for each **subdirectory individually**:

```
for dir in `ls`; do echo $dir; find $dir -name '*.php' | xargs wc -l | grep total; done;
```

That outputs something like this:

```
my_dir1
     305 total
my_dir2
     108 total
my_dir3
    1438 total
my_dir4
   26496 total
```

Answer (score 1):

I have [BusyBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BusyBox) installed on my Windows system. So here is what I did.

```
ECHO OFF
for /r %%G in (*.php) do (
busybox grep . "%%G" | busybox wc -l
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another command to get the sum of all files (Linux of course)

```
find ./ -type f -exec wc -l {}  \; | cut -d' ' -f1 | paste -sd+ | bc
```

Main difference from other answers:

1. using *find -exec*,
2. using *paste (with cut)*,
3. using *bc*

Comment: I modified this a little in my own answer to work on OS X, but shouldn't this version also have a "-" as the last argument to paste so it takes input from stdin?  Or does paste do that by default on Linux?

Comment: It does that by default. Sorry, I didnt see that it is only for OS X.

Comment: The question was generic so your answer was great for Linux (and also I liked it enough to model my OS X variant on!), just wondered if paste was really a bit different on Linux or if that was a typo to fix.

Comment: Oh now I understand your question! we're piping, so we don't need to use the - option.

Comment: It was because of the piping I had to use the "-" on OS X, to make it take input from stdin (otherwise it was looking for a file argument).  It had been so long since I last used paste on Linux I didn't remember if some versions had the default be stdin...

Answer (score 0):

I may as well add another OS X entry, this one using plain old [find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_(Unix)) with `exec` (which I prefer over using [xargs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs), as I have seen odd results from very large `find` result sets with xargs in the past).

Because this is for OS X, I also added in the filtering to either .h or .m files - make sure to copy all the way to the end!

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.[mh]" -exec wc -l {}  \; | sed -e 's/[ ]*//g' | cut -d"." -f1 | paste -sd+ - | bc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lines=0 ; for file in *.cpp *.h ; do lines=$(( $lines + $( wc -l $file | cut -d ' ' -f 1 ) )) ; done ; echo $lines
```

Answer (score -2):

```
cat \`find . -name "*.php"\` | wc -l
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score -2):

if u use window so easly 2 steps:

1. install cloc for example open cmd for admin and write next code => `choco install cloc`
2. then use cd or open terminal in folder with projects and write next code => `cloc project-example`

sreens with steps:

1. [image]
2. [image]

p.s. need move or remove folder with build project and node_modules

Answer (score -2):

You can use this windows power shell code to count any file type that you want :

```
 (gci -include *.cs,*.cshtml -recurse | select-string .).Count
```

Comment: This is not a question about powershell