# Search entire file tree Terminal

Tags: macos, bash, shell, terminal

I’m not entirely sure how to word the question but I want to pass a file argument in terminal that will search a directory and every possible subdirectory working it’s way through the whole file tree. At the moment, I’m passing `~/Classes/**/*` but I’m not sure that is working correctly

Comment: What do you want to find? Files with a specific name? Directories with a specific name? Files containing something?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said, the file tree is for an iOS app, but all it contains are folders and then obj-c files, so I'm basically looking for anything that is a file and not a directory

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to count all the lines of code in a directory recursively?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358540/how-to-count-all-the-lines-of-code-in-a-directory-recursively)

Comment: Not an excellent duplicate but you should easily find hundreds of similar questions.

Comment: How would I pass this search as an argument in a command like this?

`java -jar ~/Downloads/simian-2.3.35/bin/simian-2.3.35.jar files ~/Classes/**/*
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run this:

```
java -jar ~/Downloads/simian-2.3.35/bin/simian-2.3.35.jar files ~/Classes/**/*
```

you can do this:

```
java -jar ~/Downloads/simian-2.3.35/bin/simian-2.3.35.jar files $(find ....)
```

**Original Answer**

Basically use the `find` command:

```
find ~/Classes -type f  # find, starting in your "Classes" directory, all files

find ~ -type f  # find, starting in your HOME directory, all files

find ~ -type d  # find, starting in your HOME directory, all directories

find ~ -name "*fred*" -type f # find all files whose name contains "fred" anywhere in them

find ~ -iname "*FRED*" -type f # find all files whose name contains "fred" or "FRED" or "Fred"  anywhere in them
```

Comment: How would I pass this search as an argument in a command like this?  `java -jar ~/Downloads/simian-2.3.35/bin/simian-2.3.35.jar files ~/Classes/**/*`

Comment: Put the command I suggested inside `$()`. I have amended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `find -type d`:

```
find ~Classes -type d
```

If `~` represents the home directory, you have to add an extra slash (`/`) on it.

```
find ~/Classes -type d
```

If using bash, you'd need to enable `globstar` and add `/` to target directories:

```
shopt -s globstar
printf '%s\n' ~/Classes/**/*/
```

Comment: Given the additional comment just now, you should have `-type f` instead.

Comment: @tripleee Yeah I guess.

Comment: I'm not sure does this work when passing it into what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to run simian, a CPD detector on my project so the overall command I'm running is
`java -jar ~/Downloads/simian-2.3.35/bin/simian-2.3.35.jar files ~/Classes/**/*
`. This seems to be going to the first level of subdirectories, but I'm trying to get it to search all of them

Comment: @Killian Did you enable `globstar`? Unfortunately the solution could also match directories. If you're sure about using it, and that you're really using bash and can enable globstar, I'd make updates. Anyway as first step, please try enabling `globstar` first as I instructed.