# How to hide cat errors?

Tags: error-handling, cat

`( find -print0 | xargs -0 cat ) | wc -l` (from [How to count all the lines of code in a directory recursively?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358540/how-to-count-all-the-lines-of-code-in-a-directory-recursively)) prints the total number of lines in all files in all subdirectories. But it also prints a bunch of lines like `cat: ./x: Is a directory`.

I tried `( find -print0 | xargs -0 cat ) | wc -l &> /dev/null` (and also `2> /dev/null` and `> /dev/null 2>&1`) but the messages are still printed to the shell.

Is it not possible to hide this output?

`( find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 cat ) | wc -l` overcomes this problem, but I'm still curious why redirecting stderr doesn't work, and if there is a more general purpose way to hide errors from `cat`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to redirect the stderr stream of the `cat` command to `/dev/null`. What you have done is redirected the stderr stream of `wc`. Try this:

```
( find -print0 | xargs -0 cat 2>/dev/null ) | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `find` only to find “regular” files, you must use `find -type f …`.

By the way, if you want to calculate lines of code, you should take a look at `ohcount`.