# How can I count the number of words in a directory recursively?

Tags: bash, vim, count, grep, cpu-word

I'm trying to calculate the number of words written in a project. There are a few levels of folders and lots of text files within them.

Can anyone help me find out a quick way to do this?

bash or vim would be good!

Thanks

Comment: How do you decide whether a file is a text file? Common extension?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count all the lines of code in a directory recursively?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358540/how-to-count-all-the-lines-of-code-in-a-directory-recursively)

Answer (score 14):

use `find` the scan the dir tree and `wc` will do the rest

```
$ find path -type f | xargs wc -w | tail -1
```

last line gives the totals.

Answer (score 5):

tldr;

```
$ find . -type f -exec wc -w {} + | awk '/total/{print $1}' | paste -sd+ | bc
```

Explanation:

The `find . -type f -exec wc -w {} +` will run `wc -w` on all the files (recursively) contained by `.` (the current working directory). `find` will execute `wc` as few times as possible *but as many times as is necessary* to comply with `ARG_MAX` --- the system command length limit. When the quantity of files (and/or their constituent lengths) exceeds `ARG_MAX`, then `find` invokes `wc -w` more than once, giving multiple `total` lines:

```
$ find . -type f -exec wc -w {} + | awk '/total/{print $0}'
  8264577 total
  654892 total
 1109527 total
 149522 total
 174922 total
 181897 total
 1229726 total
 2305504 total
 1196390 total
 5509702 total
  9886665 total
```

Isolate these partial sums by printing only the first whitespace-delimited field of each `total` line:

```
$ find . -type f -exec wc -w {} + | awk '/total/{print $1}'
8264577
654892
1109527
149522
174922
181897
1229726
2305504
1196390
5509702
9886665
```

`paste` the partial sums with a `+` delimiter to give an infix summation:

```
$ find . -type f -exec wc -w {} + | awk '/total/{print $1}' | paste -sd+
8264577+654892+1109527+149522+174922+181897+1229726+2305504+1196390+5509702+9886665
```

Evaluate the infix summation using `bc`, which supports both infix expressions and arbitrary precision:

```
$ find . -type f -exec wc -w {} + | awk '/total/{print $1}' | paste -sd+ | bc
30663324
```

References:

- https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/argument-list-too-long-error-solution/
- https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/
- https://linux.die.net/man/1/find
- https://linux.die.net/man/1/wc
- https://linux.die.net/man/1/awk
- https://linux.die.net/man/1/paste
- https://linux.die.net/man/1/bc

Answer (score 4):

You could find and print all the content and pipe to `wc`:

```
find path -type f -exec cat {} \; -exec echo \; | wc -w
```

Note: the `-exec echo \;` is needed in case a file doesn't end with a newline character, in which case the last word of one file and the first word of the next will not be separated.

Or you could find and `wc` and use awk to aggregate the counts:

```
find . -type f -exec wc -w {} \; | awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }'
```

Answer (score 3):

If there's one thing I've learned from all the [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) questions on SO, it's that a filename with a space will mess you up. This script will work even if you have whitespace in the file names.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s globstar
count=0
for f in **/*.txt
do
    words=$(wc -w "$f" | awk '{print $1}')
    count=$(($count + $words))
done
echo $count
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't need to recursively count the words and that you want to include all the files in the current directory , you can use a simple approach such as:

```
wc -l *


10  000292_0
500 000297_0
510 total
```

If you want to count the words for only a specific extension in the current directory , you could try :

```
cat *.txt | wc -l
```

Comment: This answer does not handle multiple subdirectories (i.e., no recursion), and it assumes every file in the folder is a text file.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.