# How to count all the lines of code in a directory recursively using or operator to include several file types

Tags: bash, shell

I am reading this answer: [How to count all the lines of code in a directory recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358540/how-to-count-all-the-lines-of-code-in-a-directory-recursively)

But it only works for php files. I want to count recursively including javascript, html, css and php files to get the total number of combined lines of code.

I tried this `find . -name '*.php' |'*.js' | xargs wc -l`

But it does not work.

Note: I am using OS X El Capitan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a go:

`find . -name '*.php' | xargs wc -l`

With include files:

`find . -name '*.php' -o -name '*.js' | xargs wc -l`

To not include certain path:

`find . -name "*.php" -not -path "./tests*" | xargs wc -l`

Comment: thanks . what if I want to include html and css files? is the `-o` the or operator?

Comment: @RobertRocha Yes, just include `-o -name`, whenever you need to search for more files.

Answer (score 3):

to avoid using `xargs`

```
find \( -name '*.php' -o -name '*.js' -o -name '*.html' \) -exec wc -l {} +
```

- `\( \)` grouping so that all results are given to `wc` command
- add as many `-o -name` as required within `\( \)`
- use `iname` instead of `name` to ignore case of filenames
- by default, `find` works on current directory

**Reference:**

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12902/how-to-run-find-exec
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24954/when-is-xargs-needed
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters/131767#131767

Comment: You probably want a dot between the `*` and the file name extension in each instance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one liner. It uses `find` `regex` option to find for matching extensions, and `wc` `--files0-from=-` parameter to get file list from standard input

```
find -regex '.*\(php\|js\|css\|html?\)' -printf '%p\0' |wc -l --files0-from=-
```