# How to get the line-count of all the files in a directory

Tags: linux, bash

I'm asked to get the line count of all the files in some directory for which the path will be provided as a terminal argument.

My solution so far is:

```
wc -l "$1/"*
```

But doing this also gives me some unnecessary output like this:

```
wc: '/home/user/Desktop/Dir': Is a directory
```

So how can I print only the results for actual files not directories?
And then how could I only display the ones that have been edited at most 10 minutes ago?

Comment: You can just ignore the error message: `wc -l "$1/"* 2> /dev/null`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I count all the lines of code in a directory recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358540/how-can-i-count-all-the-lines-of-code-in-a-directory-recursively)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thy this:

```
find ./pathToDirectory -type f -exec wc -l {} +
```

Comment: The edit version of the question certainly works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To create a file with modification time 10 min ago

```
touch -t $(date -d '10 min ago' +%Y%m%d%H%M.%S) special_flagtime.txt
```

Add option `-newer special_flagtime.txt` or `! -newer special_flagtime.txt`
to find command.

So for example:

```
find "$1" -type f -newer special_flagtime.txt -exec wc -l {} +
```

Comment: Creating a sentinel file is a lot of work compared to just using the `-mtime` primary, which is standard (`-newer` is not).

Comment: @chepner `-mtime` cannot find files with modification time less than 10 min -mtime n `File’s  data was last modified n*24 hours ago` ; reading man page again there is the option -mmin which can be used also