# EnvDTE - How to get the text from a file in a project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, envdte

*I will ask you to please explain your answer, as I'm not acquainted with this Library*

So what I'm trying is to is get the text of all project items and count all lines.
What is the best way is approaching this problem ?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you have attempted so far.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count all the lines of code in a directory recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358540/how-to-count-all-the-lines-of-code-in-a-directory-recursively)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for you to get the count of all lines, you will need to recursively go through each folder and get the length of each files within them.

**Process the directories recursively. Get the number of lines for text files and recursively call itself for more directories**

```
    public static int GetTotalLinesInAllFiles(string targetDirectory)
    {
        int totalLines = 0;

        // Process the list of files found in the directory.
        foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory))
            totalLines += File.ReadAllLines(fileName).Length;

        // Recurse into subdirectories of this directory.
        foreach (string subdirectory in Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory))
            totalLines += GetTotalLinesInAllFiles(subdirectory);

        return totalLines;
    }
```

In your main function, you can start the call with

```
    ProcessDirectory(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
```

Comment: It is a valid answer, it worked, but i wanted to use it with EnvDTE. Anyway thanks.